# Access a Variable within a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to Check the woodCount Variable if it is equal to or greater than 25 I want to have a new button appear on the page. For now I just had it console.log true or false.

Sorry if this is really easy or makes no sense but I am new to Javascript. Thanks!

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
var woodCount = 0;
var gatherWood = document.getElementById("gatherWood");
var wood = document.getElementById("wood");



gatherWood.onclick = function(){
  woodCount++;
  wood.innerHTML = woodCount;
}


function fire() {
    if woodCount >= 25 {
       console.log('True');
  }else{
    console.log('False');
  }
}
```

HTML FILE

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Game</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Game">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <script src="game.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <input class="woodbtn" type="button" value="Gather Wood" id="gatherWood" />
   Wood = <span id="wood">0</span> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if woodCount >= 25 {` is invalid syntax, `if` conditions need parentheses around them

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a button to the DOM and keep it hidden. When it exceeds the threshold, toggle the display property from hidden to block.
2. Make sure we call the function where the toggling of style happens in the onclick event handler where incrementation occurs.

```js
var woodCount = 0;
var gatherWood = document.getElementById("gatherWood");
var wood = document.getElementById("wood");

gatherWood.onclick = function() {
  woodCount++;
  wood.innerHTML = woodCount;
  fire();
};

function fire() {
  if (woodCount >= 25) {
    document.getElementById("higherThan25")
      .style.display = "block";
  } else {
    //console.log("False");
  }
}
```

```css
.woodbtn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.woodtxt {
  text-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Game</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Game">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <script src="game.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input class="woodbtn" type="button" value="Gather Wood" id="gatherWood" />
    <input style="display: none;" class="woodbtn" type="button" value="Higher Than 25" id="higherThan25" />
    Wood = <span id="wood">0</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow Awesome, Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, can you please accept it?